# Quickbooks Online Rest API Reporting Java ERROR

Tags: java, rest, quickbooks-online

I have used a tutorial and the `Java SDK` to pull reports from the new `REST reporting API`.

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0201_ipp_java_devkit_3.0/reports

I have used the following code as specified by the tutorial:

```
    String consumerKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXTDF2GEP0tlzdGxxpQRfSb4";
    String consumerSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXYuy9CLaWiyAVHTowK0NuGMKN1X";
    String accessToken = "XXXXXXXXXXXGPU4SUGAaeyhRJFp05NUg4s8QnbY4eI4U";
    String accessTokenSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXgkz50A8Ho3Z3pgMO8QFh2ZBv3XjI";



    OAuthAuthorizer oauth = new OAuthAuthorizer(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret);  

    String appToken = "011e510ebf68ab4683b8a06b21f6228dfa03";
    String companyID = "1067363490";

    try {
    Context context = new Context(oauth, appToken, ServiceType.QBO, companyID);

    ReportService service = new ReportService(context);

    service.setStart_date("2014-02-01");
    service.setEnd_date("2014-04-20");
    service.setAccounting_method("Accrual");

    Object report = service.executeReport(ReportName.PROFITANDLOSS.toString());

        String name = "ryan";
        //System.out.println(report.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Inside `service.executeReport` it keeps throwing a `java.lang.ClassCastException`: `com.intuit.ipp.data.Report` cannot be cast to `com.intuit.ipp.core.Response`

Has anyone got these reports to work with the `Java SDK`?  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

At present reports support only Json.
Please verify that you are specifying:
Config.setProperty(Config.SERIALIZATION_RESPONSE_FORMAT, "json");

Answer (score 0):

Update Line:

```
Object report = service.executeReport(ReportName.PROFITANDLOSS.toString());
```

To:

```
Report report = service.executeReport(ReportName.PROFITANDLOSS.toString());
```

As shown here: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0500_developer_kits/0201_ipp_java_devkit_3.0/reports